# Trouble declaring union of C# classes in F#

Tags: f#

I'm using the [Forecast.io](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Forecast.io/) C# weather library, which provides several classes for weather forecasts over different time periods (e.g., hourly, daily, "right now"), which all contain similar data.

I'm trying to write functions that will accept any of these classes, but I'm getting some compile errors (below) that I don't understand:

1. For the FS0001 errors, Why is the `getTemp` function not satisfied with an object that matches the Forecast union type? Why does it expect a different parameter type in each case?
2. For the FS0019 error, what constructor is it referring to? Why is it expecting me to supply an argument to this constructor?

Here is some example code:

```
open ForecastIO

type Forecast = 
    | Currently of ForecastIO.Currently
    | HourForecast of ForecastIO.HourForecast

let getTemp forecast =
    match forecast with
        | Currently -> forecast.temperature
        | HourForecast -> forecast.temperature
    |> float

let forecastForDate date = 
    let request = new ForecastIORequest("api_key", 35.780556f, -78.638889f, date, Unit.us);
    request.Get ()

let test () = 
    let baseDate = System.DateTime.Parse "2014-06-12 22:00:00"
    let forecast = forecastForDate baseDate

    forecast
    |> (fun r -> r.currently)
    |> getTemp
    |> printfn "%f"

    forecast
    |> (fun r -> r.hourly.data.[0])
    |> getTemp
    |> printfn "%f"

test ()
```

And here is my compiler output:

```
/tmp/forecast.io/test2.fs(9,15): error FS0019: This constructor is applied to 0 argument(s) but expects 1

/tmp/forecast.io/test2.fs(23,12): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    Currently -> 'a    
but given a
    Forecast -> float    
The type 'Currently' does not match the type 'Forecast'

/tmp/forecast.io/test2.fs(28,12): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    HourForecast -> 'a    
but given a
    Forecast -> float    
The type 'HourForecast' does not match the type 'Forecast'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different issues.  One is as @mydogisbox mentions - if you DU cases have fields, you are required to consider them in your pattern matching, either ignoring them with `_` or capturing into some identifier.

The main issue, though, is that you are not creating an instance of your DU anywhere.  The `.currently` property of your forecast object might be of type `ForecastIO.Currently`, and `.hourly.data.[0]` of type `ForecastIO.HourForecast`, but that doesn't mean you can take those values and treat them like cases from your `Forecast` DU.  You need to explicitly construct the case you want:

```
  forecast
  |> (fun r -> Currently(r.currently))
  |> getTemp
  |> printfn "%f"

  forecast
  |> (fun r -> HourForecast(r.hourly.data.[0]))
  |> getTemp
  |> printfn "%f"
```

If you don't want to define a DU and instead really just want to pattern match against the type of the input, you can do something like what @Jan suggests, and not even have to define a DU:

```
let getTemp forecast =
    match forecast with
        | :? ForecastIO.Currently as c -> c.temperature
        | :? ForecastIO.HourForecast as h -> h.temperature
    |> float
```

Answer (score 4):

When decomposing DUs you need to specify the name of the constructor parameters (i.e. the parameters needed to construct that DU case).  In this case you don't want to use them so you can just blank them out like this:

```
let getTemp forecast =
    match forecast with
        | Currently _ -> forecast.temperature
        | HourForecast _ -> forecast.temperature
    |> float
```

Answer (score 0):

Works the following better?

```
let getTemp forecast =
    match forecast with
        | :? Currently as c -> c.temperature
        | :? HourForecast as h -> h.temperature
    |> float
```

Comment: You loose all the benefits of having a Discriminating Union, but yeah, it works.